# React invalid date

Tags: javascript, date, reactjs

```
var Timeframe = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
      tfs: getParameterByName('tfs'),
      tfe: getParameterByName('tfe')
  }
},
formatTime: function(time) {
    var full = new Date(time);
    console.log(time);
    console.log(full);
    return (full).toString('dddd, MMMM ,yyyy');
},
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>Timeframe: {this.formatTime(this.state.tfs)} - {this.formatTime(this.state.tfs)}</div>
    );
}
```

});

I have an outside js function called getParameterByName which, in these cases, is going to return a time in unix time.  As far as I know, Date() works very well with these numbers, and in my experience outside of React, I've never had any trouble with this.  When I try using Date within my react function, it's returning invalid date.  Does anybody know why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you verified that tfs and tfe are set correctly? e.g. outputting them in render without calling formatTime?

Comment: Yes that is working, just checked and plugged into new Date in console.  Worked fined.

Comment: Does getParameterByName return a string instead of a number?

Comment: Ahh that's it!  Sorry, I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `full.toString('dddd, MMMM ,yyyy');`

Instead of: `(full).toString('dddd, MMMM ,yyyy');`

If you need to work with *date*, a good choice is to use [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) library.